How to set a watchpoint on a string variable in Delve?
Any way to monitor when a string variable is read/write in delve? Unless I'm doing something wrong, it rejects watchpoints on string variables (because it wouldn't know the addr range to monitor as the string changes? No? Why?):
(dlv) watch -rw s
Command failed: can not watch variable of type string

Any workaround?
I tried tracking the first byte address of &s as an *int and that seemed to work but it did also hit many times in what seemed to be go's runtime code:
> watchpoint on [*(*int)(0xc0003f7130)] runtime.scanobject() /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/mgcmark.go:1317 (hits goroutine(63):3 total:78) (PC: 0x4250f2)
Warning: debugging optimized function
  1312:                 }
  1313:
  1314:                 // Keep track of farthest pointer we found, so we can
  1315:                 // update heapScanWork. TODO: is there a better metric,
  1316:                 // now that we can skip scalar portions pretty efficiently?
=>1317:                 scanSize = addr - b + goarch.PtrSize
  1318:
  1319:                 // Work here is duplicated in scanblock and above.
  1320:                 // If you make changes here, make changes there too.
  1321:                 obj := *(*uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(addr))
  1322:

I'm using go 1.21.5 and delve 1.22.1.

Strings are immutable in go. You say you want to see changes to the string, but there won't be any changes to a string, the closest you could come is to see if the s variable is re-assigned to a new string value (though maybe that's also not be possible in delve)

Yea, I guess it would be a re-assign in case of writing. Do you know if hit on read is possible ?
